# How do I get buttons for a popup module to work?

Tags: javascript

I have a "How to Play" popup that isn't responding to buttons. I have tried using class names and IDs and neither works. I am confused as to why not buttons are responding when I call the correct element/id. Can anyone provide clarity? Thank you!

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("popup-container");

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

button.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #fefbd8;
}

.popup-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 120px auto;
  background-color: #FFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 2px 30px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

.close-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #ffff;
}

.space,
.space1,
.space2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.space3 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#mybtn:hover,
#mybtn:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #A5A5A5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>

<body>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <header>
      <button id="mybtn" class="close-button" aria-label="Close" type="button">
<span aria-hidden = "true">&times;</span>
</button>
      <h1 class="share-button">How to Play</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="space">example</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using class and element Ids. I am expecting the popup to open/close with buttons.

Comment: The `<button ...>` tag should be under the `<body>` tag. It is currently above it.

Comment: Also, why's there a  `<link` inside `<body>`?

Answer (score 0):

you are having an issue with selecting elements with query selector.. you need to use dot for class name and hash for Ids ... change your 3 var lines with the following:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".popup-container");
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-button");
```

OR ... keep your js as it is and just add id="popup-container" in your container div

Comment: Or just use the correct ones of `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName()`. (For example, it currently is using `getElementById()` but the element has the name as a class, not an ID.)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes exactly !

Comment: Hello. I tried this solution exactly and it does not work. I also tried to use the id you provided. Do you have any input?